# How do I change my bot's presence in D#+?

Tags: discord, dsharp+

how do I change the discord bot presence in D#+?

Basically the presence is the dot next to someone's profile that shows if they are offline, idle, dnd and online (on discord)

And I wanna try to change my bot presence to dnd

A little reply would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: You might be able to find an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73610857/setting-the-playing-status-of-my-discord-bot-but-i-want-to-do-it-on-startup/73767917#73767917)